# Why is the receiver of this solar tower cream-colored?

Tags: optics, energy

I wonder, why the receiver of this solar tower is not black? Wouldn't a black receiver be more efficient? If not, why is it not white then, but is an intermediate color?

[image]

It seems that the receiver of other solar towers, such as Solar One is indeed black:

[image]

Does it mean that the color is not important at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the picture you posted the collector is on the other side of the tower so you can't see it. Have a look at [this PDF](http://www.nrel.gov/csp/troughnet/pdfs/2007/osuna_ps10-20_power_towers.pdf) for detailed pictures of the tower - the collector is shown on page 40, and it is indeed black.

Comment: How then it comes that the mirrors are closer to the camera than the tower?

Comment: Don't know. Remember that PS10 has PV panels as well as mirrors. What you're interpreting as mirrors might actually be the PV panels.